# Настройка Apache для нескольких сайтов

Tags: apache

**Добрый день!**

В общем, есть apache сервер настроенный по умолчанию, на котором крутится сайт, скажем example.ru.

Есть второй apache сервер, также настроенный по умолчанию, на котором также крутится сайт, но без хостинга, и доступен по ip, скажем 10.0.0.102.

Оба сайта в одной локальной сети и друг друга видят. Оба сервера настроены одинаково: ubuntu 18.04LTS, apache2, php7.2, mysql

Как настроить на этих двух машинах, Apache так, чтобы первый сервер подтягивал второй скажем в example.ru/test

Говоря о настройках по умолчанию, я имею ввиду это:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Заранее большое спасибо

Comment: Это так не работает. example.ru и example.ru/test это один сайт example.ru. Виртуальные хосты можно настроить на test.example.ru, но тогда вам нужно прописывать что test.example.ru должен вести к 10.0.0.102 через ДНС или hosts

Comment: @ArchDemon , спасибо. Его достаточно тупо прописать в hosts, или что-то еще?

Comment: У клиентов нужно прописывать в файл hosts, если это винда, если линукс, то я не в курсе куда писать, но тоже можно. Если такой вариант не прокатывает, то нужна ДНС запись